# Can't compile code with libevent library using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, libevent

I use CMake in VS Code to build project with libevent. I add it to project

```
find_package(LIBEVENT REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
  PUBLIC
  ${LIBEVENT_LIB}
)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
  PUBLIC
  ${LIBEVENT_INCLUDE_DIR}
)
```

And pass -levent flag to linker

```
target_link_options(TEST-CMAKE PUBLIC "-L/E:/Projects/C++/.libraries/libevent-2.1.12-stable/build/lib -levent -levent_core")
```

if i don't use any functions in code it compiles without errors, but if i use some, it fails with error

```
undefined reference to `event_base_dispatch' (same with other functions)
```

I found that problem might be in flag order, but i don't know how to change it in cmake

code i try to compile

```
#include <iostream>
#include <event2/event.h>
int main()
{    
    
    event_base* evbase;
    event_base_dispatch(evbase);
}
```

I have Windows 10, GCC 11.3.0

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(TEST-CMAKE VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_executable(TEST-CMAKE main.cpp)

find_package(LIBEVENT REQUIRED)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
  PUBLIC
  ${LIBEVENT_INCLUDE_DIR}
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
  PUBLIC
  ${LIBEVENT_LIB}
)

target_link_options(TEST-CMAKE PUBLIC "-L/E:/Projects/C++/.libraries/libevent-2.1.12-stable/build -levent -levent_core")

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

Comment: Are you using a `FindLibEvent.cmake`, by accident? Can you edit your question with a link to it? Because the `target_link_libraries` call should be enough, no need to specify your own linker flags.

Comment: You mean, do i use separate cmake file only to find libevent? Code in question is inside CMakeLists.txt, i don't use other files. I added CMakeLists.txt to question.

Comment: Please post the output from cmake configuration. Did it found libevent? `${LIBEVENT_LIB}` It's `LIBEVENT_LIBRARIES` looking at https://github.com/libevent/libevent/blob/master/cmake/LibeventConfig.cmake.in#L8. or libevent::core

Comment: I changed `${LIBEVENT_LIB}` to `${LIBEVENT_LIBRARIES}` and problem disappeared! Thanks a lot! Could you, by the way, say where is best place to find names of cmake variables? Because i've also seen `${LIBEVENT_LIB}` variant a lot.

Comment: For built-in CMake packages the documentation is hosted by CMake itself, for third-party CMake packages you need to read the corresponding `findXXX.cmake`.

Comment: Thanks! I hope this will help, because i also had problem when i wrote LIBEVENT lowercase and cmake couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `find_package` https://github.com/libevent/libevent/blob/master/cmake/LibeventConfig.cmake.in#L8 you should be able to just:

```
find_package(Libevent REQUIRED)
add_executable(TEST-CMAKE main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(TEST-CMAKE libevent::core)
```